# Way to maximize screen area

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I have this screen structure in my app:

[image]

Which is tremendous waste of area. Mainly in the system bar and the action top bar.
I would like to:

1. Move the app logo and title to the system area
2. Narrow the height of the tabs
3. Move the menu to the bottom action bar

To get something like this:

[image]

Comment: Are you using ActionBar or ActionBar sherlock? if you are using ActionBar Sherlock library then in your Application tag set `android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"`

Comment: @Pragnani I am not familiar with ActionBar Sherlock. I use the class `ActionBar`.

Comment: @Pragnani I get this: *"error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme.Sherlock')"*

Comment: No, Not that.. I have posted answer below..please check that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to hide the main action bar. As it is described in [Android Developer's site](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html#SplitActionBar):

> If you'd like to hide the main action bar at the top, because you're
>   using the built-in navigation tabs along with the split action bar,
>   call *`setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)`* to disable the application icon
>   in the action bar. In this case, **there's now nothing left in the main
>   action bar**, so it disappears and all that’s left are the navigation
>   tabs at the top and the action items at the bottom, as shown by the
>   second device in figure 3.

That's necessary, but not enough, because the main action bar still shows the title and the menu icon on the right. Two more steps are required:

1. Hide the icon and Title

   ```
   setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
   ```
2. Do not create a menu in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`

Now the main action bar is empty and it indeed dissapears. The tabs still show. The menu is lost, but you can create a button somewhere in your screen to act as menu, even you can use the same icon.

**Tab Height**
And I found out that the tab height can be controlled through XML style. Adding this to the styles.xml inside the app style tag

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">35dp</item>
</style>
```

**System Bar**
It seems to be that the system bar is, as its name suggest, for system only use, not user. I did not find any clue to whether the elements in there can be modified (exception being notification icons from services)

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing remove the title and appicon from this TabLayout.

Use for your activity in androidmanifest.xml

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"     
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Using this parameters your layout will be looking like this see it

[image]

Comment: I think that the TABs are part of the action bar title (at least they are added  as `actionbar.addTab()` according to the latest guide from android Developer's site); and if I disable it those will go too. I will try it anyway to see what comes up.

Comment: At first glance my application crashes on each of both suggested themes. I have to debug to see why is that.

Comment: @iolmambo Show the stacktrace.